# Languages Offering Scalability for Server-client Application

Tags: client-server, scalability

I want to learn how to get started with developing highly scalable server/client applications--more specifically for non-web-based/not-in-a-browser desktop clients.  I figure that developing a very minimalistic chat application (roughly comparable to AIM/Skype) is a reasonable way to get started down such a path of learning about servers/clients and scalability.

I am unsure which programming language would be appropriate for this task considering my emphasis on scalability.  Personally, the only languages I am interested in working with are Java, C#, and C/C++.  As far as the server OS goes, I will be dealing with Linux, so C# in my case would imply Mono.

I suppose my specific interest boils down to what language to use on the server, since it is the infrastructure supporting the application which has to be highly scalable.  I have heard mixed reviews of Java and C# server scalability.  My intuition would suggest that they are both perfectly reasonable choices, but then I hear about others running into problems once they reach a certain threshold of application/user traffic.  It is hard to know what to make of hearsay, but I do suppose that the lack of bare-metal support of these languages could hinder scalability at certain thresholds.  When I hear about C/C++, I hear mention of the great Boost libraries (ex. such as `Boost.Asio`) offering the ultimate scalability.  But then I am scared off when I hear that sockets in particular are much more complex to deal with in C/C++ than with other languages like Java/C#.

What is an effective way to get started in making highly scalable server-client applications such as a chat client?  Of the ones which I have mentioned, which programming language is adequately suited for developing such applications?  What other languages should I consider for such an application?

EDIT: the term "scale" most directly relates to scaling to serve a large number of users (perhaps tens or hundreds of thousands, maybe millions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the languages you mentioned will scale.

If your serious about this, you should choose the language you know best and build it - you havent even prototyped your idea yet and your concerning yourself with scale.

We could list many programs and websites written in each of the languages above that scale perfectly well (We can also list many that dont).

Answer (score 1):

"Scale" - in which way has it to scale? Scaling with CPU cores, with users or with code base?

You could ask: Which language implementation is the fastest? Which language will handle a lot of requests without problems?

In every language implementation you will need to have strategies to build a distributed system. If you have to worry about speed, you should rather worry about having a possibility to distribute your system on many machines.

If you want maximal scalability in terms of cores and non-blocking request, go with Erlang. It will handle a shitload of traffic on server side.

Comment: I was definitely thinking about having multiple servers to build a distributed system.  Also, by "scale" I meant scaling to server a large number of users (just picking a random number, think 100k users, for example).  I will revise my question to specify.

Comment: Well, as I said, it's not about the language, it's about the strategy. You may go with C, which may give you the fastest results, but will fail for many concurrent requests.